# ExecutorService is not shutting down

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code

```
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    es.submit(new Runnable() {
           @Override public void run() 
           {
                  while(true);

            }
   });

es.shutdownNow();
```

The problem is that the ExecutorService doesn't shutdown after I call shutdownNow. Documentation says that it Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks.

So why is the ES failing to shutdown?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did this and it worked:

```
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    es.submit(new Runnable() {
           @Override public void run() 
           {
                  while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());

            }
   });

   es.shutdownNow();
```

the reason is that `shutdownNow` doesn't terminate the thread. it just interrupts all running threads.

Comment: As  while(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
evalutes to false in first execution.

Comment: The condition is wrong: with `while(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());` the code runs only while being interrupted, which is probably contrary to what it is supposed to do - you will want it to run *until* it gets interrupted: `while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());`

Comment: @all thank you. Yes, if I do this: `while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());` it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't shut down a thread that just refuses to terminate. It's just like you cannot force a thread to terminate, when it is running an infinite loop.

From the Javadoc for `shutdownNow()`: "There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate."

So unless your thread responds to an interrupt (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html), there's not much else `shutdownNow()` can do to terminate a thread.

Answer (score 1):

`isInterrupted()` returns true if and only if thread's execution is interrupted.

```
     ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        es.submit(new Runnable() {
               @Override public void run() 
               {   // infinite loop to process

                       while(true)
                       {                              
                          // We've been interrupted: no more processing.
                          if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                             return;
                           }
                       }

                }
       });
   es.shutdownNow();
```

Answer (score 0):

The key phrase in the documentation is "attempts to".
By having simple `while(true)` in the loop, you give the thread no chance to be interrupted.
Try putting a `sleep()` call in the loop.

Answer (score -2):

Please try this

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
es.submit(new Runnable() {
       @Override public void run() 
       {
             try{
                while(true);
             }catch(InterruptException){
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
             }
        }
```

});
es.shutdownNow();

Comment: This won't work, as no methods are called that throw `InterruptedException`. Like the other answers say, you have to check the thread's `isInterrupted()` status.