# Future.get(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS) doesnt timeout after 5 seconds if native methods are used in Java

Tags: java, future, native-methods

I am using Executor framework in my java code. I am facing an issue and i need clarification regarding the same. 
Below is my java code,

```
ExecutorService executorObj = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        String name = "default";
        Future<String> futRes =  executorObj.submit(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() {
                computePropertyPage("");
                return "Hello";
            }
        }); 

        try {
            System.out.println("waiting for name for 5 seconds maximum...");
             return futRes.get(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.out.println("Exception occurred : " + e);
            return name;
        }
```

In the above code, computePropertyPage() is a native method. Its properly linked with the java code. But the call to the function is not getting completed. Its stuck indefinitely. If the call is stuck for more than 5 seconds, i am expecting TimeOutException after 5 seconds. But i am not recieving it.

Instead of native method call, if i just add a sleep of 10 seconds as below,

```
try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);    
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get TimeOutException.

I just want to know if its the limitation from the java side that it dont have control on the native methods and thats the reason its not able to throw TimeOutException for **futRes.get(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);**

Answer (score 0):

Your method `computePropertyPage` completes in less than 5 seconds and return response. Since you aren't calling `shutdown` on `ExecutorService` it isn't terminating. Try calling `executorObj.shutdown();`

Comment: No Sukhpal..I dont think not calling shutdown has an issue as the same code works if i sleep for 10 seconds without using native method. i also tried to put a log statement before and after the native method call. after log doesnt come. It just prints before log and its hung. So this confirms that native method has not finished its execution.

Comment: Can you tell what all your native method does? May be a snippet? AFAIK not calling shutdown will hung up your application.

Comment: Actually i dont have control on the native method. its some body else's code which i am integrating. I just want to know if usage of native methods has any impact on the Future.get().

Comment: Your native method doesn't check whether thread is interrupted or not and refuses to terminate. For more information check similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514606/executorservice-is-not-shutting-down